# Banned account in SQL not working

Tags: php, mysql

Why can't i block users with banstatus "Banned" from accessing the website? The error now is that the php banned all users from accessing the website even when their banstatus is not banned. Please help to identify the error as i have been trying to solve the error for a long time and couldn't solve it still. Thank you in advance :)

These are my codes:

```
    if(!empty($_POST['username'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    }
    else
    {
    $username=null;
    echo "<font color='red'> Please enter your username! </font></p>";  
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['password'])){
    $password= md5($_POST['password']);
    }
    else
    {
    $password=null;
    echo "<font color='red'> Please enter your password! </font></p>";
    }

    if ($username && $password) {


        $connection = mysql_connect("", "", "", "");

        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

        $db = mysql_select_db("", $connection);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' and active=1", $connection);
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($rows == 1) {
            if ($rows['banstatus'] == '') {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location:somewhere.php");
           }
            else{
                echo "<br><br><br><b><font color='red'>Your account has been banned. Please contact the administrator.</font></b><br><br>"; 
            }
       }        
        else {
        echo "<br><br><br><b><font color='red'> Login is not successful.</font></b><br><br>";   
        }
        mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
       }
```

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: *Edited*: `if ($row['banstatus'] == 'Banned') { echo "You are banned!!"; }` inside a fetching function/loop. Yours is failing now. `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){...}`. And `mysql_error()` would have told you about it

Comment: **Don't** store passwords unhashed in the database. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: `$rows` is a count of the number of rows (`$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);`), not an array with a 'banstatus' value... you need to fetch the row from the result set that the query has retrieved

Comment: Btw, don't use this in a live environment; you **will** get hacked.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- !!! it works ^^ I'll also take note of the other stuff that was said. Thanks a lot guys :D

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)***

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_POST['username'])){
$username=$_POST['username'];
}
else
{
$username=null;
echo "<font color='red'> Please enter your username! </font></p>";  
}

if(!empty($_POST['password'])){
$password= md5($_POST['password']);
}
else
{
$password=null;
echo "<font color='red'> Please enter your password! </font></p>";
}

if ($username && $password) {


    $connection = new mysqli($your_db_IP_ADDR, $your_db_username, $your_db_pass, $your_db_database_name);

    /*$username = stripslashes($username);*/ //if you using mysqli real_escape_string you don't need to stripslashes
    /*$password = stripslashes($password);*/ //MD5 is an hash. You don't need to stripslashes it
    $username = $connection->real_escape_string($username);
    /*$password = $connection->real_escape_string($password)*/ // your $password is an MD5 hash. You don't need to escape it;



    $results = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' and active = 1");

    if ($results->num_rows === 1) {
        $row = $results->fetch_assoc(); //call it row, it just one
        if ($row['banstatus'] === '') {
           session_start();
           $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
           $connection->close(); // Closing Connection also HERE before redirect
           header("Location:somewhere.php");
       } else {
            echo "<br><br><br><b><font color='red'>Your account has been banned. Please contact the administrator.</font></b><br><br>"; 
       }
   } else {
    echo "<br><br><br><b><font color='red'> Login is not successful.</font></b><br><br>";   

   }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Comment: A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: personal curiosity. Yours is a negative critique, an admonition, or is it a constructive criticism? I corrected the code by commenting it in key areas

Comment: It is *constructive*. Commenting in the code by itself tends not to help the OP or future visitors as all they see is a wall of code with no apparent explanation for changes or modifications.

Comment: I'm sorry for having suspected :)